# How to effectively motivate a person to upload landscape orientation photos in a mobile app?

Tags: mobile-application, uploading, screen-orientation

The application provides users a way to upload one or several photos at once. How can it effectively motivate a person to shoot or upload landscape orientation photos?

Comment: Why do you want them to upload just horizontal photos? What's the context? My first thought would be to let them upload all photos and show some kind of hint/warning on all vertical ones.

Comment: Is it a requirement or a recommendation?

Comment: Have you tried any options already, or are you asking us to come up with the ideas for you?

Comment: It is not forbidden to upload vertical photos, just it doesn't suit for the design concept. Cropped photos are not way out.

Landscape orientation photoes take more useful area on screen.

Comment: I've tried, I have some ideas, they are:

1) At the screen of already loaded pictures suggest user to upload horizontal photos.
2) Starting the Camera, making a suggestion on screen that better to turn the phone. 
3) Initially open Camera in landscape orientation.
4) To crop photos up to exact size, for instance 4:3 (like Instagram)

I'm just asking for an advice, which idea the best one?
Of course, I can't forbit to upload portrait photos.

Answer (score 1):

first question: why would you want to promote landscape photos as compared to portrait?
Which works best depends entirely on the subject of the photo, thus you will need to look for your solution there, make it natural for the users to create landscape format photos rather than portrait format.

Of course we all know that people use their phones to make photos, they will tend to try to fit everything into portrait mode because that's the way they're used to holding their phone.
Maybe a suggestion on screen that they can turn their phone 90% can help? A red border around the screen that flashes to green when the phone is in landscape mode maybe? It's subtle, but might get peoples' attention.